# PDF marked up in OSX Preview loses all formatting once i try to re-edit after saving

Tags: pdf, preview

I have an issue when i use OSX's preview tool to markup a PDF, at first the markup works fine, but if i save the PDF and re-open it to edit the text the text loses all its formatting.

In the example below the PDF was originally created with Google Drive, but i have seen this happen in many PDFs including ones published with other PDF saving software.

Any ideas why this is happening and what i can do to prevent it ?

Im running OSX 10.13.6

Here is the PDF, pre re-edit

[image: Here is the PDF, pre re-edit]

Here is the PDF once i try and re-edit.

[image: Here is the PDF once i try and re-edit]

Comment: Does the text "lose all its formatting" or reset to whatever Preview's current settings are for text annotations?

Comment: Probably better to use a different tool if you are doing a lot of pdf editing, like pdfpen.

Comment: @benwiggy it seems to default to red background, standard text, text box not sized. Ive tried changing the current settings and trying again, but it seems to revert to the above

Comment: @TomGewecke ill check it out, i also have acrobat pro, so im a bit loathed to have another paid piece of PDF software, but the acrobat pro software becomes very slow when doing markups

Comment: I notice you're on High Sierra. Apple rewrote PDFKit in Sierra, and introduced lots of bugs that continued through 10.13. I'm unable to reproduce this bug on Mojave.

Comment: There have been other issues reported here re issues with `Preview`; e.g.  [1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/384948/preview-on-catalina-fails-to-select-or-copy-text-in-pdf), [2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372321/macos-catalina-preview-print-save-as-pdf-not-really-working). Apple has acknowledged at least one bug - it seems likely there are others.